# SQL script behaves differently when run from PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have about 5 million records in a database table (MySQL 5.6), and I wanted to get the last 2 dates, grouped by ID. Looking around the web, I found examples that allowed me to cobble together the following...

```
SELECT id, date 
FROM 
(
    SELECT *,   
    @id_rank := IF(@current_id = id, @id_rank + 1, 1) AS id_rank,   
    @current_id := id 
    FROM `data` 
    ORDER BY id DESC, date DESC
) ranked 
WHERE id_rank <= 2 
ORDER BY id ASC, date DESC
```

Running this code from MySQL Workbench, returned 5,700 rows, which is what I expected. I then tried to call this SQL as-is from PHP, using the following SQL string...

```
$subSql =
    "SELECT *, " .
    "  @id_rank := IF(@current_id = id, @id_rank + 1, 1) AS id_rank, " .
    "  @current_id := id " .
    "FROM `data` " .
    "ORDER BY id DESC, date DESC";

$sql =
    "SELECT id, date " .
    "FROM ($subSql) ranked " .
    "WHERE id_rank <= 2 " .
    "ORDER BY id ASC, date DESC";
```

However, running this code resulted in out-of-memory. I them modified the code to return a count of the number of records expected, and instead of the expected 5,700 rows, it returned 4,925,479. So my question is "what do I have to change in my PHP SQL above, to get the correct results that I was getting from MySQL Workbench".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning variables in MySQL has been deprecated.  You should be using window functions:

```
SELECT id, date 
FROM (SELECT d.*,  
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) as id_rank 
      FROM `data` d
     ) d 
WHERE id_rank <= 2 
ORDER BY id ASC, date DESC;
```

Even in older versions your code is not guaranteed to work *because MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions*.  You are assigning the variable in one expression and using it in another -- and those can go in either order.

If your `date`s are unique per `id`, you can do this without variables:

```
select id, date
from (select d.*,
             (select d2.date
              from data d2
              where d2.id = d.id and d2.date >= d.date
              order by d2.date desc
              limit 1 offset 1
             ) as date_2
      from data d
     ) d
where date >= date_2 or date_2 is null;
```

For performance, you want an index on `data(id, date)`.

Comment: Yes, I had seen that, but I'd read that ROW_NUMBER() was only available from MySQL 8.0. I'm using 5.6.

Comment: Thanks again for your very fast responses :-)
I just tried to run your example in MySQL Workbench, and the connection was lost after 60 seconds, so I now need to check if there is a way to speed this up. The original SQL was taking 6-7 seconds.
BTW, id+date is unique, and I also have indexes on id and date.

Comment: @Wannabe-Coder . . . Try it with the index.

Comment: OK, I have given up on this and gone down the route of using a stored procedure to do the job. However, I will mark your answer as being the correct one, as that would have been a better solution, had I been able to use it.

Comment: this is all relatively new to me, so when you say "Try it with the index", do you mean force it to use one of the indexes that I mentioned?

Comment: @Wannabe-Coder . . . The index recommended in the answer is on `data(id, date)`; I have no way of knowing if this is an existing index.